# Replace an html element with it's index via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to replace an `HTML element` i get via it's index, I'm trying this but it won't work:

```
<div class="results">
    <div id="61">Result 1 content</div>
    <div id="8762">Result 2 content</div>
    <div id="234">Result 3 content</div>
</div>

<script>
    var index = 0;
    var html = '<div id="243">Result 1 content</div>';
    var element = $('.results').get(index);
    element.replaceWith(html);
</script>
```

how can I replace an entire `HTML element` by getting it by it's `index`?

Comment: Why are you replacing an entire element just to change its ID?

Comment: Oh yea, just pollute the global namespace with all those variables. I'm sure nothing can go wrong. `:P` (Use a function wrapper, for crying out loud.)

Comment: this is just an example, I need to do it by `each` or via `for` depending by the situation, sometimes i get a list of results via `JSON` and i need to replace the elements starting by the 0 to the ##. In other cases i just need to update them in runtime.

Comment: I assume the element which you want to replace is a child of the `.results` element, if it is not or if you need help adapting the function to work with your use case give a holler.

Comment: `get()` will get the native DOM element, which does'nt have a replaceWith method as it's not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.results div').eq(index).replaceWith(html);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy4pB/)

You should use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to filter the set of matched elements inside a jQuery object by its index. Also `$('.results')` only has 1 element (itself). I assume you're looking for the `div`s inside of it.

---

Also if you have `div`s inside of your `div`s, use the more specific [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('.results > div').eq(index).replaceWith(html);
```

Which has the same effect as using the [`.children` method](http://api.jquery.com/children/) with a selector filter:

```
$('.results').children(':eq(' + index + ')').replaceWith(html);
```

Or more simply, concatenating it all in a single selector:

```
$('.results > div:eq(' + index + ')').replaceWith(html);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy4pB/1/)

There are many other ways to get this done with jQuery, but these should be more than enough. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

`.get` retrieves the DOM element at the index. What you're looking for is [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = 0
$($('.results div')[index]).replaceWith('<div id="243">Result 1 content</div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = $('.results').find('div');
```